# Clearing JTextFields' field

Tags: java, swing

How do we clear a JTextField's field after inputing something in that field? Note: I made the JTextFields in my JOptionPane

Comment: You have setText() in [JTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html). Use it. *Why people do not read docs?*

Comment: @Harry Joy - It makes them feel more clever:P

Comment: Is the question that simple???? I was thinking in something like "que field has a default text, the user begins to type, the default text is removed"...

Comment: @woliveirajr O yeah... I wanted to ask that too... Do you know the solution?

Comment: @Marco yep, but it would be better if you ask it in a specific question, explaining a bit better what you want, giving examples, saying what you have tried so far

Comment: @woliveirajr Thanks for the tips, I'll keep them in mind :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well to clear a `JTextField`, if you have a reference to it you can set the text to ""

```
field.setText("");
```

Answer (score 3):

To clear a specific `JTextField` call `field.setText("")`. If you need something else please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

Just call `setText("")` instance method for the textfields.